# What was the reason behind the fall of Buddhism in India?

Tags: history, early-buddhism

Buddhism was originated from India.It spread all accross the world, many countries are called as Buddhist countries.

Lord Buddha was the most scientific, serene, logical and kind person of the world, anyone becoming his enemy seems to be impossible. There was a time when almost whole of the India was Buddhist. Then, what caused the decline of Buddhism in India?

Comment: I wrote (with references) about a subject related to that, in my answer to this topic on Skeptics.SE -- [Were Buddhists murdered en masse during the first Muslim conquest of India?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/37575/2703)

Comment: This is nearly an exact duplicate of the topic [Why is Buddhism followed mainly outside of India when it originated there?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3338/254) (so I think this topic ought to be closed as a duplicate).

Comment: I think the other topic talks about following Buddhism outsite India. I am not sure whether it clearly highlights the **reason of its fall In India.**

Comment: May this will help you. [Decline of Buddhism in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decline_of_Buddhism_in_India).

Comment: Here is a book exactly answer your question  [DECLINE AND FALL OF BUDDHISM 
(A tragedy in Ancient India)  
By  
Dr. K. Jamanadas](https://drambedkarbooks.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/decline-and-fall-of-buddhism-by-dr-k-jamnadas.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

After the Pari-nibbhana of The Buddha, there was a decline of Theravada Buddhism ( those who follow the teaching preserved in the Pāli), and a rise of the Mahayana Buddhism. The third council got underway to make the monastic order of those who follow the teaching preserved in the Pāli.  With time Mahayana Buddhism rose up again. It was a death blow to those who wanted to keep the teaching preserved in the Pāli.  Mahayanists translated the Dhamma into Sanskrit and rejected attaining of the Marga- phala of the Theravada School.

At the time only the Brahmins’ Veda was written in Veda and Sanskrit languages. Brahmins never felt that other religions will be a threat to their own since Veda as it was the only religious script written in Sanskrit. However, after the translation of the Mahayana scriptures into Sanskrit by the Mahayanists, the Brahmins started reading these translated texts and to argue pointing out its content.

In trying to defeat these Brahmins, the Mahayanists built large universities like Nalanda with the aim of learning the Veda. The language used in these universities was Sanskrit. They tried to outdo the Brahmins. They tried to argue with the Brahmins. Thus what came to pass was exactly as mentioned in the Alagaddūpama Sutta, which states that “if anyone tries to learn my teachings to argue with others, then he will be destroyed like the man who tried to catch a snake by its tail.”

When the monks won an argument the monks got the king to make the Brahmins their servants in the Nalanda University. The monks were beheaded when Brahmins won their arguments. The Brahmins went for the kill, because of the change that these monks have made to the Brahmin society. A Sothern Indian Brahmin called Sankarāchārya rose up to destroy the power of these monks. The Musālman invaded India at this time. The Brahmins got them to first destroy Buddhism, or at least what was left of it. This was how the Buddhism got wiped out from India.

It was the moguls that did most of the killing of Buddhist Monks, and the process of decline continued until Buddhism got fully wiped out in India by the end of the 12th century, when Somapura Mahavihara (in the present day Bangladesh) was set ablaze. In 1199 CE Odantapuri Mahavihara close to Nalanda was burnt down after killing all the monks. Buddha’s place of Enlightenment, Bodhgaya too was attacked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's a lot of factors regarding this. 
The Monks started to liberate the buddha's teaching.
The Buddhism started to decline after the 4th buddhist council of India. Unlike King Asoka, King Kanishka of Kushan Empire, not keeping the precepts and still going on wars with other empires. He chose the most Sangha in the community back then the Sarvastivadin-Mahayana.

The last was because of the invasion of Turkic-muslim-Mamluk Dynasty which ended the Most Enormous Buddhist University, Nalanda.

As what Buddha said in DN16 Mahaparinibbana Sutta, there are 7 things x 7, which prevent decline in the community.

> Now at that time venerable Ānanda was stood behind the Gracious One
>   fanning the Gracious One. Then the Gracious One addressed venerable
>   Ānanda, saying:
>
> 1) “Have you heard, Ānanda: ‘The Vajjians assemble regularly and
>   assemble frequently?’” “I have heard this, reverend Sir: ‘The Vajjians
>   assemble regularly and assemble frequently.’” “For as long, Ānanda, as
>   the Vajjians will assemble regularly and assemble frequently surely
>   growth, Ānanda, is to be expected for the Vajjians not decline.
>
> 2) Have you heard, Ānanda: ‘The Vajjians assemble unanimously, rise
>   unanimously, and carry out their Vajjian duties unanimously?’” “I have
>   heard this, reverend Sir, that the Vajjians assemble unanimously, rise
>   unanimously, and carry out their Vajjian duties unanimously.” “For as
>   long, Ānanda, as the Vajjians will assemble unanimously, rise
>   unanimously, and carry out their Vajjian duties unanimously, surely
>   growth, Ānanda, is to be expected for the Vajjians not decline.
>
> 3) Have you heard, Ānanda: ‘The Vajjians do not establish new laws
>   that were not established, or cut off old laws that were established,
>   and carry on with such laws as were accepted in the Ancient Vajjian
>   Constitution?’” “I have heard this, reverend Sir: ‘The Vajjians do not
>   establish new laws that were not established, or cut off old laws that
>   were established, and they carry on with such laws as were accepted in
>   the Ancient Vajjian Constitution.’” “For as long, Ānanda, as the
>   Vajjians do not establish new laws that were not established, or cut
>   off old laws that were established, and they carry on with such laws
>   as were accepted in the Ancient Vajjian Constitution surely growth,
>   Ānanda, is to be expected for the Vajjians not decline.
>
> 4) Have you heard, Ānanda: ‘The Vajjians honour the elders of the
>   Vajjians, respect, revere, worship and think them worth listening
>   to?’” “I have heard this, reverend Sir: ‘The Vajjians honour the
>   elders of the Vajjians, respect, revere, worship and think them worth
>   listening to.’” “For as long, Ānanda, as the Vajjians will honour the
>   elders of the Vajjians, respect, revere, worship and think them worth
>   listening to, surely growth, Ānanda, is to be expected for the
>   Vajjians not decline.
>
> 5) Have you heard, Ānanda: ‘The Vajjians do not coerce and force their
>   women and girls to dwell with them against their will?’” “I have heard
>   this, reverend Sir: ‘The Vajjians do not coerce and force their women
>   and girls to dwell with them against their will.’” “For as long,
>   Ānanda, as the Vajjians will not coerce and force their women and
>   girls to dwell with them against their will, surely growth, Ānanda, is
>   to be expected for the Vajjians not decline.
>
> 6) Have you heard, Ānanda: ‘The Vajjians honour the Vajjian shrines
>   amongst the Vajjians, both within and without the city, respect,
>   revere, and worship them, and do not allow the righteous sacrifices
>   that were formerly given, formerly made, to be neglected?’” “I have
>   heard this, reverend Sir: ‘The Vajjians honour the Vajjian shrines
>   amongst the Vajjians, both within and without the city, respect,
>   revere, and worship them, and do not allow the righteous sacrifices
>   that were formerly given, formerly made, to be neglected.” “For as
>   long, Ānanda, as the Vajjians will honour the Vajjian shrines amongst
>   the Vajjians, both within and without the city, respect, revere, and
>   worship them, and do not allow the righteous sacrifices that were
>   formerly given, formerly made, to be neglected surely growth, Ānanda,
>   is to be expected for the Vajjians not decline.
>
> 7) Have you heard, Ānanda: ‘The Vajjians have made good arrangements
>   in regard to the lawful protection, safety, and guarding of the Worthy
>   Ones, so that Worthy Ones in the future can enter the realm, and
>   having entered the Worthy Ones can live comfortably in the realm?” “I
>   have heard this, reverend Sir: ‘The Vajjians have made good
>   arrangements in regard to the lawful protection, safety, and guarding
>   of the Worthy Ones, and that the Worthy Ones in the future can enter
>   the realm, and having entered the Worthy Ones can live comfortably in
>   the realm.” “For as long, Ānanda, as the Vajjians will make good
>   arrangements in regard to the lawful protection, safety, and guarding
>   of the Worthy Ones, and that the Worthy Ones in the future can enter
>   the realm, and having entered, the Worthy Ones can live comfortably in
>   the realm, surely growth, Ānanda, is to be expected for the Vajjians
>   not decline.”
>
> Then the Gracious One addressed the Magadhan chief minister the
>   brahmin Vassakāra, saying: “At one time, brahmin, I was living near
>   Vesālī near to the Sārandada Shrine and there I taught the Vajjians
>   these seven things which prevent decline. For as long, brahmin, as the
>   Vajjians maintain these seven things which prevent decline, and the
>   Vajjians agree with these seven things which prevent decline, surely
>   growth, brahmin, is to be expected for the Vajjians not decline.”
>
> After this was said, the Magadhan chief minister the brahmin Vassakāra
>   addressed the Gracious One, saying: “If the Vajjians, dear Gotama,
>   were endowed with even one or the other of these seven things which
>   prevent decline, surely growth is to be expected not decline, what to
>   say about having seven things which prevent decline? The Vajjians
>   cannot be overcome, dear Gotama, by the Magadhan King Ajātasattu, the
>   son of Lady Wisdom, by war, but only through diplomacy, or through the
>   breaking of an alliance. And now, dear Gotama, we shall go, as we have
>   many duties, and there is much which ought to be done.”
>
> “Now is the time, brahmin, for whatever you are thinking.” Then the
>   Magadhan chief minister the brahmin Vassakāra, after greatly rejoicing
>   and gladly receiving this word of the Gracious One, rose from his seat
>   and departed.
>
> 3: Seven Things which Prevent Decline in the Community (1–7)
>
> Then the Gracious One, not long after the Magadhan chief minister, the
>   brahmin Vassakāra, had gone, addressed venerable Ānanda, saying: “Go,
>   Ānanda, and whatever monks there are living in dependence on Rājagaha,
>   assemble them in the Attendance Hall.”
>
> “Very well, reverend Sir,” said venerable Ānanda, and after replying
>   to the Gracious One, and assembling whatever monks there were living
>   in dependence on Rājagaha in the Attendance Hall, he approached the
>   Gracious One, and after approaching and worshipping the Gracious One,
>   he stood on one side.
>
> While standing on one side venerable Ānanda said this to the Gracious
>   One: “The Community of monks have assembled, reverend Sir, now is the
>   time, Gracious One, for whatever you are thinking.”
>
> Then the Gracious One after rising from his seat approached the
>   Attendance Hall, and after approaching he sat down on the prepared
>   seat. While sitting the Gracious One addressed the monks, saying:
>
> “I will teach you seven things which prevent decline, listen to it,
>   apply your minds well, and I will speak.” “Very well, reverend Sir,”
>   those monks replied to the Gracious One, and the Gracious One said
>   this:
>
> 1) “For as long, monks, as the monks will assemble regularly and
>   assemble frequently, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the
>   monks, not decline.
>
> 2) For as long, monks, as the monks will assemble unanimously, rise
>   unanimously, and carry out their Community duties unanimously, surely
>   growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 3) For as long, monks, as the monks do not establish new laws that
>   were not established, or cut off old laws that were established, and
>   they carry on with such training-rules as have been accepted, surely
>   growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 4) For as long, monks, as the monks will honour the elder monks, those
>   of long-standing, a long time gone-forth, the Fathers of the
>   Community, the Leaders of the Community, respect, revere, worship and
>   think them worth listening to, surely growth, monks, is to be expected
>   for the monks, not decline.
>
> 5) For as long, monks, as the monks will not come under the influence
>   of craving which has arisen for continued existence, surely growth,
>   monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 6) For as long, monks, as the monks will have desire for forest
>   dwellings, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not
>   decline.
>
> 7) For as long, monks, as the monks individually will attend to the
>   ways of mindfulness, so that their fellow celibates, who are
>   well-behaved, in the future can come, and having come to their fellow
>   celibates, who are well-behaved, can live comfortably, surely growth,
>   monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> For as long, monks, as the monks will maintain these seven things
>   which prevent decline, and the monks will agree with these seven
>   things which prevent decline, surely growth, monks, is to be expected
>   for the monks, not decline.
>
> 4: Seven Further Things which Prevent Decline in the Community (8–14)
>
> I will teach you a further seven things which prevent decline, listen
>   to it, apply your minds well, and I will speak.”
>
> “Very well, reverend Sir,” those monks replied to the Gracious One,
>   and the Gracious One said this:
>
> 1) “For as long, monks, as the monks are not devoted to the pleasure
>   in work, the delight in work, and are not attached to work, surely
>   growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 2) For as long, monks, as the monks are not devoted to the pleasure in
>   speech, the delight in speech, and are not attached to speech, surely
>   growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 3) For as long, monks, as the monks are not devoted to the pleasure in
>   sleep, the delight in sleep, and are not attached to sleep, surely
>   growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 4) For as long, monks, as the monks are not devoted to the pleasure of
>   company, the delight in company, and are not attached to company,
>   surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 5) For as long, monks, as the monks do not have evil wishes, do not go
>   under the influence of evil wishes, surely growth, monks, is to be
>   expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 6) For as long, monks, as the monks do not have wicked friends, do not
>   have wicked companions, do not have wicked comrades, surely growth,
>   monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 7) For as long, monks, as the monks do not achieve only mundane or
>   incomplete attainment, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the
>   monks, not decline.
>
> For as long, monks, as the monks will maintain these seven things
>   which prevent decline, and the monks will agree with these seven
>   things which prevent decline, surely growth, monks, is to be expected
>   for the monks, not decline.
>
> 5: Seven Further Things which Prevent Decline in the Community (15–21)
>
> I will teach you a further seven things which prevent decline, listen
>   to it, apply your minds well, and I will speak.”
>
> “Very well, reverend Sir,” those monks replied to the Gracious One,
>   and the Gracious One said this:
>
> 1) “For as long, monks, as the monks will have faith, surely growth,
>   monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 2) For as long, monks, as the monks will have a conscientious mind,
>   surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 3) For as long, monks, as the monks will have a sense of shame, surely
>   growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 4) For as long, monks, as the monks will be learned, surely growth,
>   monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 5) For as long, monks, as the monks will be strenuous, surely growth,
>   monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 6) For as long, monks, as the monks will attend to mindfulness, surely
>   growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 7) For as long, monks, as the monks will possess wisdom, surely
>   growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> For as long, monks, as the monks will maintain these seven things
>   which prevent decline, and the monks will agree with these seven
>   things which prevent decline, surely growth, monks, is to be expected
>   for the monks, not decline.
>
> 6: Seven Further Things which Prevent Decline in the Community (22–28)
>
> I will teach you a further seven things which prevent decline, listen
>   to it, apply your minds well, and I will speak.”
>
> “Very well, reverend Sir,” those monks replied to the Gracious One,
>   and the Gracious One said this:
>
> 1) “For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the factor of
>   Perfect Awakening that is Mindfulness, surely growth, monks, is to be
>   expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 2) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the factor of Perfect
>   Awakening that is Investigation of the nature of things, surely
>   growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 3) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the factor of Perfect
>   Awakening that is Energy, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for
>   the monks, not decline.
>
> 4) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the factor of Perfect
>   Awakening that is Rapture, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for
>   the monks, not decline.
>
> 5) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the factor of Perfect
>   Awakening that is Calm, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for
>   the monks, not decline.
>
> 6) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the factor of Perfect
>   Awakening that is Concentration, surely growth, monks, is to be
>   expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 7) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the factor of Perfect
>   Awakening that is Equanimity, surely growth, monks, is to be expected
>   for the monks, not decline.
>
> For as long, monks, as the monks will maintain these seven things
>   which prevent decline, and the monks will agree with these seven
>   things which prevent decline, surely growth, monks, is to be expected
>   for the monks, not decline.
>
> 7: Seven Further Things which Prevent Decline in the Community (29–35)
>
> I will teach you a further seven things which prevent decline, listen
>   to it, apply your minds well, and I will speak.”
>
> “Very well, reverend Sir,” those monks replied to the Gracious One,
>   and the Gracious One said this:
>
> 1) “For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the perception of
>   impermanence, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks,
>   not decline.
>
> 2) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the perception of
>   non-self, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not
>   decline.
>
> 3) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the perception of the
>   unattractive, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks,
>   not decline.
>
> 4) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the perception of
>   danger, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not
>   decline.
>
> 5) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the perception of
>   giving up, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not
>   decline.
>
> 6) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the perception of
>   dispassion, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not
>   decline.
>
> 7) For as long, monks, as the monks will develop the perception of
>   cessation, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not
>   decline.
>
> For as long, monks, as the monks will maintain these seven things
>   which prevent decline, and the monks will agree with these seven
>   things which prevent decline, surely growth, monks, is to be expected
>   for the monks, not decline.
>
> 8: Six Things which Prevent Decline in the Community (36–41)
>
> I will teach you a further six things which prevent decline, listen to
>   it, apply your minds well, and I will speak.”
>
> “Very well, reverend Sir,” those monks replied to the Gracious One,
>   and the Gracious One said this:
>
> 1) “For as long, monks, as the monks with friendly actions by way of
>   the body will serve their fellow celibates, both in public and in
>   private, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not
>   decline.
>
> 2) For as long, monks, as the monks with friendly actions by way of
>   speech will serve their fellow celibates, both in public and in
>   private, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not
>   decline.
>
> 3) For as long, monks, as the monks with friendly actions by way of
>   the mind will serve their fellow celibates, both in public and in
>   private, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not
>   decline.
>
> 4) For as long, monks, as the monks in regard to those righteous
>   gains, received in accordance with the Teaching—whatever amount has
>   been received in the bowl—will divide and share such gains with those
>   who are virtuous, fellow celibates, and share them in common, surely
>   growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 5) For as long, monks, as the monks are endowed with those virtues
>   which are unbroken, faultless, unspotted, unblemished, productive of
>   freedom, praised by the wise, not clung to, leading to concentration,
>   and will live endowed with virtue amongst their fellow celibates who
>   themselves possess such virtue, both in public and in private, surely
>   growth, monks, is to be expected for the monks, not decline.
>
> 6) For as long, monks, as the monks are endowed with that which is
>   Ariyan View, which leads out, which leads to the complete destruction
>   of suffering for one who acts thus, and will live endowed with Right
>   View amongst those who themselves possess such Right View, both in
>   public and in private, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the
>   monks, not decline.
>
> For as long, monks, as the monks will maintain these six things which
>   prevent decline, and the monks will agree with these six things which
>   prevent decline, surely growth, monks, is to be expected for the
>   monks, not decline.”
>
> There also the Gracious One, while living near Rājagaha on the
>   Vultures’ Peak Mountain, spoke frequently to the monks about the
>   Teaching, saying:
>
> “Such is virtue, such is concentration, such is wisdom, when virtue is
>   well-developed it yields great fruit and brings great advantages in
>   regard to concentration, when concentration is well-developed it
>   yields great fruit and brings great advantages in regard to wisdom,
>   when wisdom is well-developed the mind is completely liberated from
>   the pollutants, that is to say: the pollutant of sensuality, the
>   pollutant of craving for continued existence, the pollutant of
>   ignorance.”

The declination of buddhism was because of breaking these.

Hopefully this helps. If you want to know more about this, you can try to read this book called "The concise history of buddhism".